# How do I avoid gap when using z-index in CSS?

Tags: css, xhtml

I have the following HTML code:

```
  <div class="outer_container">
     <div id="imgContainer">
       <img src="/some/image" />              
     </div>

     <div id="slogan">
       <span class="quote">Some text here</span>
     </div>

     <div id="footer" class="gray_top_border">
       Some text here
     </div>
  </div>
```

And this is my CSS:

```
.outer_container {
  background-color:#FFFFFF;
  margin:0 auto;
  width:960px;
}

#slogan {
  font-size: 3em;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 999;
  bottom: 50px;
  left: 50px;
}

#footer {
  border-top:1px solid #B5B5B5;
  min-height:50px;
  padding:10px;
}
```

Using this code, I get a 3em gap between image and footer.
If I change position from `relative` to `absolute`, the gap problem is gone. But then the top / left position is relative to the browser window, and not within the DIV container.

How can I float text over the image without creating this gap?

Comment: @stevan you gave slogan as relative , if so why did you give them bottom and left , it should be only for position:absolute right.

Comment: @stevan , if the footer wants to stap 50px from bottom and left you should make footer as absolute and parent as relative

Comment: You probably haven't set the parent container's position, you need to do this for the `#slogan` element to have the desired effect, please post the rest of your CSS so we can see how the element is interacting with others :)

Comment: @Kyle: Added rest of the code now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does it:

```
#slogan {
  font-size: 3em;
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  overflow: visible;
  z-index: 999;
  bottom: 50px;
  left: 50px;
}
```

Comment: is it good practice to give postion relative and bottom , left

Comment: No it's not good practice, but I was answering the question. The fact is, adding those two parameters (height and overflow) does work to remove the gap, and however you set the position after that is a different matter.

Comment: Thanks Nathan, this worked. Probably not an ideal solution, but it works :)

Comment: PS. Why is using bottom, left not good practice when suing realtive position?

Comment: It causes bugs. There's no reason it's not an ideal solution unless you need to set the height of the positioned element. If you do, just stick a div inside it and set the height of that... but we're starting to get into hacky territory if we do that. :)

Answer (score 0):

can you try the below css.

```
 #slogan {
      font-size: 3em;
      position: relative;
      z-index: 999;
      margin-top:-20px;

    }

    #footer {
position:absolute;
bottom:10px

      border-top:1px solid #B5B5B5;
      min-height:50px;
      padding:10px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

"Position: relative" still reserves the area the text would have been in. This means it can make some weird padding/margin issues once in a while.

"position: absolute" does not reserve the area. I recommend just using that instead of hacking around with the relative one.

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

You can wrap the whole thing in a new div that's position: relative then your absolute pixels will go out from that instead of screen 0,0.

"*An absolute position element is positioned relative to the first parent element that has a position other than static. If no such element is found, the containing block is .*"